# I have this caret that wil not display as intended

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a caret, with this code that seemed ok, but my caret is not displaying at all.

**The Code:**

```css
.caret {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.caret:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 12px;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid white;
}
```

```html
 <li>
   <a href="#">
     <h3>Home</h3>
   </a>
   <span class="caret">
</li>
```

This I strongly believe should be working. Can anybody please tell me why it is otherwise?

Comment: Try closing `<span class="caret">` with `</span>`. Also maybe you don't see your caret because it has white border on white background?

Comment: just did  that but still nothing. Is there anything wrong with my html of the css

Answer (score 1):

Your `.caret` is white and not visible on white background. So change to another color.

```css
h3 {
  display:inline-block;
}
.caret {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.caret::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 12px;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <h3>Home</h3>
  </a>
  <span class="caret"></span>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, but the caret is been created over colored background. Is there no way to have white caret?

Comment: provide a example with the error. maybe there is a item overlays the caret or some other problems we don't know (and we can't see in your example).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.caret {

  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.caret::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 12px;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<li><a href="#"><h3>Home</h3></a><span class="caret"></li>
```